# RasPi Python - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Trying to get a py working on my Raspberry Pi that is running ok on Win10.

Keep getting

```
%Run File.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/File.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tornado import websocket, web, ioloop
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'
```

I am using Thonny to edit/run on the Pi; the shell is showing Python 3.6.6

On the Pi, I've tried all of these (after I did sudo update/upgrade):

- Installed Python3.6.6 (same as on my Win10)
- sudo pip install tornado
- sudo python3 -m pip install tornado

Any other things I could try to get this working?

Comment: try to start python and import tornado by hand right in terminal, watch which python is actually started

Comment: Try `sudo apt install python3-tornado`

Comment: That yields:

Python 3.6.6 (/usr/local/bin/python3.6)
>>> %Run my.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/my.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tornado import websocket, web, ioloop
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'
>>>

Comment: Following @vav advice -- I opened console, entered python3 --version  and it shows 3.5.3. This is different than Thonny.  So I tried "from tornado import *" and it gave no errors.